# Two e-mails/one account issue

Tags: facebook

Two emails/one account issue. I recently deactivated my old Facebook account, and made a new one for my sister using the same email surprisingly it worked. Every time I try to login to my old account using my email and password it brings me to my sister's account.

How can I get my old account back?

Answer (score 1):

You have deactivated your account and now you want reactivate the account but when you are login using email address and password, it is login to your sister account as you have created an account with the same email id for your sister.

In this case, if you had created username for your account, try login with the user name, or if you had verified you mobile number, try login using mobile number instead of email address. If you are able to login, change the email address for your account or your sister's account. Do not use same email address for two accounts, two accounts are not allowed for one person. It against the Facebook privacy policy (multiple accounts with single email address, they consider it belongs to one person).

If above both method do not work, login to your sister's account, change the primary email address (better remove your email address from her account). Once your email id is free, you will be able to reactivate your account.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, unfortunately I never verified my  Facebook mobile number and it didn't work logging in with my username and  password I created. I logged in to my sister's fb account  and removed my email account and added her own primary email but when I tryed to log in to my old account it brings me back to my sister's even though I deleted my email from her account. I also submitted a form to Facebook a while ago but they never responded

Comment: Enter your email address and click on the forget password. And follow the instructions. See if you are able to get your account.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Didn't work means what? What is it telling?

Comment: It sends a conformation code and just gives me the option to make a new password for the new account  ( my sisters account)

Comment: Remove your email from your sister's account. Then you should be able to recover the old one.

Comment: I did that and when I logged in it said my email doesn't match any account!

Answer (score -1):

If you have registered a username with Facebook you can try to log in with username@facebook.com on the email field.

Your username, is listed on your profile URL:

> https://facebook.com/**username.here.123** 
>   (Highlighted part is your username )

So, try using

**username.here.123**@facebook.com on the login form.

Once you regain access to the account, change the email address registered on both your sisters and your account. Have your sister register hers for her account. You should be able to restore your credentials then.

Also, if you have registered and verified a mobile phone number, use the number instead of any email in the login form.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, but I can't get access to my old account profile Username because it is already deactivated. And I already submitted a form from Facebook and they haven't responded in a while, any further support from you would be great .